# Slider problems (using JQuery and Coffeescript)

Tags: jquery-ui, coffeescript

I'm just learning jquery-ui and have been playing with the sliders with the goal of integrating it into my app.

Caveat - the code below is in Coffeescript.

I have this slider (copied from the site example) and have tweaked some options.  It seems to work fine.

```
$('#slider-range').slider
    range: true
    ..........
    slide: (event, ui) ->
      $('#amount').val '$' + ui.values[0] + ' - $' + ui.values[1]
      return
  $('#amount').val '$' + $('#slider-range').slider('values', 0) + ' - $' + $('#slider-range').slider('values', 1)
  return
```

I can use slider-range in any of my pages and it works.

I removed some of the code because it works.  However I have tried to implement two more sliders but they do not appear to load.

```
$('#treble').slider
return

$('#bass').slider
return
```

I ran into a problem with the datapicker (which i use in another app) and that will not load either.

I'm using CDN for my files, that would be JQuery 3.2.1 and JQuery-UI 1.12.1

I find it puzzling that one slider works, the other two do not.  Any suggestions? I didn't post my layout file to keep the post shorter.

I do not see any issues in Inspector / Devtools.

I'm adding my head directives in the event the problem is there.

```
doctype html
html lang="en"
  head
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do the elements, `#treble` and `#bass`, exists in your HTML?

Comment: @Twisty: Sort of, missing `$ ->` (AKA `$(function() { ... })`) wrapper.